# CSS File Editing for Teams? (how to avoid stepping on each others' feet?!)

Tags: version-control, css, file-handling

I'm wondering if anyone has a good solution for when you're working as a team and there's a single file used throughout a project (like a styles.css file) and everyone needs to use it throughout the day - inevitably someone will make changes and save without grabbing the most recent version first. Is there some sort of group editing program for Windows/web? We currently just access the CSS files via FTP & edit in our usual editors. Probably an editor that can load & save changes on the fly?

Comment: Do you use any version control?  If not, use it.

Comment: Use version control instead of FTP.  It will not allow you to accidentally overwrite someone else's committed changes.

Comment: if you're using a single file it still can be a problem to coordinate because some version control systems require you to exclusivly check-out the file so noone else can work on it.  You won't have any lost changes ,but you'll constantly be seeing people hoving over one another's desk going ' done yet? check it in so i can work on it'.  And don't get me started on branching the file.  Best advice? try to segment your file into multiple conceptual pieces, some which may change rapidly, and some not.

Comment: But aren't there some web apps specifically for group editing? Google has/had one that allowed you to see your co-worker's text change as he/she typed it, and then you could go and color it, draw, etc. - someone HAS to have come up with something like that for developers, right?!

Comment: Editing the same file at the same time (like in google docs) would be a real mess. For example: You change your css while your coworkers edit the same file at the same time. Now lets say that you want to test your CSS but your coworker is editing at the same time... the CSS wont compile.

Comment: @tylerl i suppose these kinds of programs have their utility, but only if the editing is extremely interactive and all parties can be brought online at the same time.  typically, at least in computer programming the edits tend to be longer you need multiple people working, but each takes a long time to finish any unit of work.  the real trick is when you have work that depends on other work, this is where source control essentialy fails you as a multiuser concurrency control.  you need to layout the structure of the function, CSS classes, in a way that facilitates bullding/sharing others work

Answer (score 2):

Use Git.

Git is a version-control system that has features specifically for this purpose. You can make changes to a file concurrently, and then Git tries to merge the two together automatically. When it can't merge them reliably, it tells you there are conflicts and asks you to resolve them.

I say use Git over other version-control systems (SVN, CVS, etc..) because in my experience, Git's merging capabilities are better. It has always seemed to be able to automatically merge stuff better than SVN. That may have changed since I last used SVN, however.

Comment: as far as i'm concerned there is no way to automatically merge two versions a file or two changesets to a file.  it's basically breaking a fundamental law of some kind, like Nyquist, Shannon, or Thermodynamics.

some programs can try to guess what would be a good way to merge separate parts of file, but if the change in the semantic meaning of one set of changes impacts another, all bets are off.

Comment: also, even if no significant changes in semantic meaning are involved, say , just a reorganization, or cleaning up of, code, i find it extremely hard to believe any non-[AI-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI-complete) program could do any justice to trying to merge two users heads toether, as GIT likes to refer to them.

Comment: Maybe I'm just too tired & preoccupied at the moment, but it seems to me like the solution to this should be more specific and elegant... While I'm typing in a class, the editor should be recording every keystroke and sending it out to my colleagues' editors. It should enact my changes only when I've saved, and otherwise just ignore my edits until that point... Fellow editors just need to see that I'm working on that class/ID section so they know to stay away from it. It could put a timestamp for when each line was changed. I'm fed up with every editor being a dumb one-way communicator...

Comment: @Andyz Git knows when it can't merge automatically and asks for human help in such cases. It works very well.

Comment: @tylerl You’re basically describing locking version control, and that has proved not to work very well in practice.

Answer (score 1):

This is a notably succinct, demonstrative, explanation of the problem, the potential solutions, and in my opinion; and contrary to Joel's exuberance about his new Mercurial tool;  a fatal blow to the entire idea of getting out of multi-user editing conflicts easily.

http://hginit.com/04.html

Note the 'graphical tool' that Joel uses when a merge conflict appears.  This is virtually no improvement on Visual SourceSafe, which has been maligned for decades, but still serves it's essential purpose.  But that purpose is not merging automatically.  Without proper architecture of your CSS classes / files, source control is hardly going to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control).

If you find your team is uncomfortable with merges and it doesn't cause too much of a bottleneck, you could use a VCS that supports locking such as [SVN](http://subversion.apache.org/) or [Veracity](http://veracity-scm.com/).

In Veracity, the workflow would be something like:

```
vv lock styles.css
# make changes to the file
vv commit
vv push
```

Each team member **must** remember to lock the file before editing. If someone else has the file locked they will be told to wait their turn.